# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value

Tags: mysql, asp.net, type-conversion

I am planning to insert a specific value to my textbox from a different table. Upon doing this, it gives me an error" Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '5,000 to data type int. In my database, creditrequest column (5000) is char and the destination column is int. Any tricks on this?

here is my code:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection scn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 'PAULO'; Initial Catalog=ShoppingCartDB;Integrated Security =True"))
        {
            scn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO UserData(CreditRequest) Select CreditRequest FROM CreditRequests Where Username=@Username", scn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Session["New"];

            object value = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

            if (value != null)
                txtCredit.Text = value.ToString();
        }
```

the error is with

```
object value = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO UserData(CreditRequest)  SELECT CAST(REPLACE(CreditRequest, ',', '') as int) FROM CreditRequests Where Username=@Username
```

Comment: all inside the quotation?

Comment: inserted into database but not showing to textbox sir

Comment: Your question was regarding the conversion error, which is solved. I would suggest starting a new question if you are having another problem. Thanks

Comment: makes sense. will do. may i ask you another question. how can i insert the credit request value for the right username? because right now its being inserted to the database and makes  new ID's.